# How to check if mysql query returns nothing?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I'm writing a project and at the some point i have to check if there is an entry in database which matches the content of `id-textbox` and `password-textbox`. But I don't know how to indicate in my backend code(VB) that the query returns nothing.

This is the code I am using. But it doesn't work somehow. Error messages Are not being prompt:

```
Try
    myconn.Open()
    Dim stquery As String = "SELECT * from accountstbl WHERE user_ID = " & IdNumb.Text
    Dim smd As MySqlCommand
    Dim myreader As MySqlDataReader
    smd = New MySqlCommand(stquery, myconn)
    myreader = smd.ExecuteReader()
    If myreader.Read() = True Then
        If myreader.Item("user_ID") = IdNumb.Text Then
            If myreader.Item("password") = CurrPass.Text Then
                'some code if the user input is valid
             Else
                errorPassID.Visible = True
             End If
        Else
           errorPassC.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
    myconn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim ErrorMessage As String = "alert('" & ex.Message.ToString() & "');"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", ErrorMessage, True)   myconn.Close()
End Try
```

Will appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: Are you expecting only one result set back, or can there be multiple matches?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to check if the reader return rows and if not, emit an error message.
Also, do not use string concatenation to build queries, use always parametrized queries

```
        myconn.Open()
        Dim stquery As String = "SELECT * from accountstbl WHERE user_ID = @id"
        Dim smd = New MySqlCommand(stquery, myconn)
        smd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(IdNumb.Text))
        Dim myreader = smd.ExecuteReader()
        if Not myreader.HasRows Then
            Dim ErrorMessage As String = "alert('No user found');"
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", ErrorMessage, True)
            myconn.Close()
            return
        else
            myreder.Read()
            ' no need to check if id is equal, you pass it as parameter to a where clause'
            If myreader.Item("password") = CurrPass.Text Then
                 'some code if the user input is valid '
            Else
                 errorPassID.Visible = True
                  ' or error message '
            End If
        End If
        myconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim ErrorMessage As String = "alert('" & ex.Message.ToString() & "');"
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ErrorAlert", ErrorMessage, True)
        myconn.Close()
    End Try
```

Note also that passing a clear text password along the wire is a serious security hole. I hope you  have stored an hash of the password and check on that instead.

By the way, why don't pass also the password hash in the query? Somthing like this:

```
  Dim stquery As String = "SELECT * from accountstbl WHERE user_ID = @id AND password = @pwd"
```

In this way, if you have a record returned the user is validated and your client side code will be simple

Comment: I don't believe `MySqlDataReader` has the `HasRows` property - at least not according to the documentation I saw.  Would be the easiest way if it does, though.

Comment: MySqlDataReader implements DbDataReader, I can't test it now, but I expect that the property is there

Comment: I'm splitting it into 2 because I need to prompt 2 types of error messages. One if password is invalid another if a user id is wrong

Comment: All right then, but, again, you are giving too much information to wannabee hackers. If you tell them that the user is right but just the password is wrong, you are cutting 50% of their work. Oh well, perhaps I am a bit paranoid here.